# Is it possible that Daenerys might come again?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Towards​ the end of *Game of Thrones*, we see Jon Snow

> stabbing Daenerys, not in the chest, but somewhere around stomach. This leads me to think there might be a chance for her to still be alive.
>  [image: Jon Snow holding a stabbed Daenerys]

Is there any indication that she might come back for the Iron Throne at some point in the future?

Comment: I am not even sure if this is "future work policy", as there will not be future work. The tv show has ended, and we can assumed she is indeed death, and won't be somehow resurected.

Comment: isn't this community think about fiction and fantasies ? i think now we can fantasise about Daenerys Targaryen after unconfirmed death !

Comment: this StackExchange is indeed dedicated to fantasy, but not speculation or fan theories.

Comment: @Kepotx - OP is asking if she's ***definitely dead***. That question is answerable without speculation or opinion.

Comment: you indeed answer the question well, saying that she is dead. Still, even it it's quite improbable, it's still possible that she resurect and come back for the throne

Comment: I think the pool of her blood all over the floor, and the famously poor skill level of dragons at performing transfusions, rules out any possibility of survival. Of course, *Game of Thrones* is a world where magic resurrection is possible.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Cold temperature can staunch blood loss.

Comment: Must... refrain... from saying dirty joke!

Comment: @Valorum: that didn't do much for Jon up at the Wall!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [script reading](https://twitter.com/enidinthecity/status/1132842164080267264?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1132842164080267264&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nme.com%2Fnews%2Ftv%2Fwatch-kit-harrington-cry-when-he-realises-jon-snow-is-to-murder-daenerys-in-game-of-thrones-2493044) makes it abundantly clear that the dagger penetrated her heart and killed her.

> For a moment neither moves, as if moving would make this real. We see
>   Jon with his hand on the dagger that he just lodged **in Dany's heart**.
>
> **Her strength leaves her and she collapses to the marble**. He keeps her
>   in his arms and she falls.
>
> Kneeling down to the floor beside her, he looks down at what he's
>   done, terrible and necessary. End of Game of Thrones.

That being said, this is a world where [resurrection is a thing](https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7qE2fiT5seO2lIre/giphy.gif), so there's always the *possibility* that she'll pop up in a future episode, but I wouldn't hold your breath.

Comment: A future episode?

Comment: that is script bot scene we seen in show :-), so it's possible ;- D

Comment: @Randal'Thor - TV show revivals are reasonably common; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revival_(television)#List_of_television_series_revivals

Comment: I mean, Jon Snow himself was resurrected from the exact same thing... :p